Solidity Add Timer So It Would Get Executed By Itself
Is there a way that set a time from 10 minutes from now and call a function by itself or a change a struct's element?

You can use Chainlink Automation to achieve that functionality.
It provides three kinds of triggers depending on the use-case:

Time-Based - calling function in a regular interval like cron jobs.

Custom Logic - calling function depending on some custom logic.

Log Trigger - calling function depending on emitting of event.


